# Spring Security DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Now im migrating from xml config to java and have some problems.
I have custom PermissionEvaluator beside a SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("*mypackages*")
@Configuration
@Import(MethodSecurity.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//couple of beans//

}
```

i created a subclass for GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurity extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
        return defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }
}
```

All of these are initialized in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.getRootConfigClasses as separate config classes. And MethodSecurity.createExpressionHandler() normally invoking and returning the DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.

But with this config my method security doesnt work at all, customPermissionEvaluator is not invoking. I have seen that in applicationContext no DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler bean! But DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler exists (with DenyAllPermissionEvaluator).
Which is not invoking too, because i can access to my methods.

And finally i made this work by adding in SecurityConfig method:

```
@Autowired
private CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator;
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
        web.expressionHandler(handler);
    }
```

After this, my custom customPermissionEvaluator is invoking but in applicationContext i have DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler with my customPermissionEvaluator (as i did), and no DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler. 
So why GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration doesnt create DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler ?

I'm worrying because when i was using xml-config with this definition:

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>
```

i had in my applicationContext properly created DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler with my customPermissionEvaluator, and DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler with DenyAllPermissionEvaluator, that was not used. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your class MethodSecurity  loaded with other @Configuration classes ? Probably you are not importing this class or it is in a package that is not scanned by Spring.

Comment: Yes it is loaded,as i wrote inAbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.getRootConfigClasses. And while app bootstraping my MethodSecurity.createExpressionHandler is calling and DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler is created and returned, but then no DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler in applicationContext.